# add_action which contains first argument admin_print_scripts-$page

Tags: actions

Here I am not getting whats the meaning passing `$page`  with admin_print_scripts ?

My code is like :

```
$page = add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type, __('text', 'plugin-dir-name'), __('text', 'plugin-dir-name'), 'edit_posts', 'text_' . $post_type, array(&$this, 'text_list_admin'));
add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$page", array(&$this, 'text_scripts'));
```

I have read

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts-%28hookname%29

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts

but whats the difference between them?

**Update**

I want to add those script on 
http://domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order&page=member_list&type=order_cal

Here when am giving `$page='shop_order_page_member_list';` it applies on all member_list page but I want to apply on specif page so I tried `$page='shop_order_page_member_list_type_order_cal';` but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts echos inline javascript in all admin pages header but http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts-%28hookname%29 echos inline javascript in specific admin page header passed as second parameter.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so please can you help me how to pass that specific admin page in my case, I am updating my question

Comment: question updated

Comment: @Er.KT This may help you http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add_action-admin_print_scripts-for-a-specific-admin-page

Answer (score 0):

Answer for my updated question
I have used

```
$page='shop_order_page_member_list';
```

but with condition like

```
if($_GET['type']=='order_cal'){
 $page='shop_order_page_member_list';
}
```